# Ansible iterate a dictionary with lists

Tags: ansible

I have the following variable loaded via `include_vars`:

```yml
access:
    username-foo:
      - path: /
        permissions: rwX
        recursive: true

    username-bar:
      - path: /
        permissions: rX

      - path: /css
        permissions: rwX
        recursive: true

      - path: /data
        permissions: rX

      - path: /data/reviews.yml
        permissions: rw

      - path: /js
        permissions: rX

      - path: /js/*.js
        permissions: rw
```

I want to feed this information to the `shell` command in order to set appropriate permissions.

I've tried some techniques from here:
http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html
but failed to come up with working solution.

Is it possible to iterate this structure? If not, how do I re-structure it in order to make it work? Is it possible to do this without breaking the DRY rule (e.g. include username into every record)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First off, you might want to consider using the [`file` module](http://docs.ansible.com/file_module.html), rather than `shell`.  It's less failure prone, and ostensibly idempotent.  However, that might give you some issues with mixing directories, files, and file globs.  YMMV.

As for the heart of the question, I would set up your variables like so:

```
users:
  - username: bar
    directories:
      - path: /data
        permissions: rX
      - path: /js
        permissions: rX
  - username: foo
    directories:
      - path: /
        permissions: rwX
```

The play would then look like this:

```
- name: Change mod/own
  shell: chown {{ item.0.username }} {{ item.1.path }};chmod u+{{ item.1.permissions }} {{ item.1.path }
  with_subelements:
    - users
    - directories
```

Comment: Great idea! Thanks! Works like a charm. BTW I'm using `shell` module because I need to do recursive ACL and that is not supported by the `acl` module.

Comment: Solid logic.  Looks like `shell` is your best bet with ACLs and recursion.

Comment: BTW is it possible to ignore missing hash key like `recursive` in my example? When I try to access it and it's missing, Ansible will stop the execution of the playbook and throw an exception. I prefer not to add `recursive: false` to every record.

Comment: I think the default syntax should work:  `{{ some_variable | default() }}`.  So, in this case:  `{{ item.1.recursive | default(false) }}`

Comment: How would the task change if the "directories" key is just a list instead of a dictionary also?

Answer (score 7):

This is a good output example that you can try yourself.
Create a new playbook called `iteration_loop.yml`:

```
---

- name: Change mod/own
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: show me the iterations
    debug: msg={{ item.0.username }} {{ item.1.path }} then {{ item.1.permissions }} {{ item.1.path }}
    with_subelements:
      - users
      - directories
  vars:
    users:
      - username: bar
        directories:
          - path: /data
            permissions: rX
          - path: /js
            permissions: rX
      - username: foo
        directories:
          - path: /
            permissions: rwX
```

Then run the playbook like this:
    `ansible-playbook -i '172.16.222.131,' iteration_loop.yml`

and the output should give you how the items are accessed:

```
PLAY [Change mod/own] ********************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [172.16.222.131]

TASK: [show me the iterations] ************************************************ 
ok: [172.16.222.131] => (item=({'username': 'bar'}, {'path': '/data', 'permissions': 'rX'})) => {
    "item": [
        {
            "username": "bar"
        }, 
        {
            "path": "/data", 
            "permissions": "rX"
        }
    ], 
    "msg": "bar"
}
ok: [172.16.222.131] => (item=({'username': 'bar'}, {'path': '/js', 'permissions': 'rX'})) => {
    "item": [
        {
            "username": "bar"
        }, 
        {
            "path": "/js", 
            "permissions": "rX"
        }
    ], 
    "msg": "bar"
}
ok: [172.16.222.131] => (item=({'username': 'foo'}, {'path': '/', 'permissions': 'rwX'})) => {
    "item": [
        {
            "username": "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "path": "/", 
            "permissions": "rwX"
        }
    ], 
    "msg": "foo"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
172.16.222.131             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `dict={a:[1,2,3],b:[1,2]}` and so on:

```
- name: Flattened list
  set_fact:
    flattened: "{{ dict.values() | sum(start=[]) }}"
```

Now `flattened == [1,2,3,1,2]`

Answer (score 0):

I will reformat your vars to below format:

```
access:
- username: foo
  directories:
    - path: /
      permissions: rwX
      recursive: true

- username: bar
  directories:
    - path: /
      permissions: rX
      recursive: false

    - path: /css
      permissions: rwX
      recursive: true

    - path: /data
      permissions: rX
      recursive: false

    - path: /data/reviews.yml
      permissions: rw
      recursive: false

    - path: /js
      permissions: rX
      recursive: false

    - path: /js/*.js
      permissions: rw
      recursive: false
```

and then my playbook as below:

```
tasks:
- name: Iterate the vars inside var4 when recursive
  debug: msg="username is {{ item.0.username }} and path is {{ item.1.path }} permission is {{ item.1.permissions }} and recursive"
  when: item.1.recursive
  ignore_errors: true
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ access }}"
    - directories
- name: Iterate the vars inside var4 when no recursive
  debug: msg="username is {{ item.0.username }} and path is {{ item.1.path }} permission is {{ item.1.permissions }}"
  when: not item.1.recursive
  ignore_errors: true
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ access }}"
    - directories
```